# Probability function and distribution - taking out fish from a pool

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

> In a pool of fish there are 4 fish of type A, 3 fish of type B, 2 fish of type C, 1 fish of type D.
>
> We take out fish without returning them until we get fish of type C for the first time.
>
> We define $X$ to be the sum of fish taken out.
>
> 1. Find the probability function of X.
> 2. What is the probability of taking out fish of type D while taking fish out of the pool?
> 3. What is the distribution of the number of fish of type B taken out?

I can calculate the values of the function for each value of $X$ separately:

$p(x=1)=\frac 2 {10}, p(x=2)=p\{(AC),(BC),(DC)\}=...=\frac 8 {45}$ but it's starting to become too long for $x=3$ and I don't see any pattern. Maybe it should be something like:

$p(x=k)=\frac {\binom{10}{k-1}(k-1)!\cdot \text{something}}{\binom{10}{k}(k)!}$

The $k-1$ because type C is always at the end, but I don't see how to decrease the different values and add them with each iteration...

As for 2 and 3, do we need to make another function for them or we can use the same function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: for calculating $p(x = 2)$, you don't need to work out $p(AC), p(BC), p(DC)$ separately, you just need to work out $p((\text{not-}C)C)$, which is $\frac{8}{10}\frac{2}{9}$. Can you see how to generalise this?

Hint for part 2: work out the conditional probability $p(\text{the fish of type D gets taken out}|x=r)$, then use the law of total probability and part 1 to work out $p(\text{the fish of type D gets taken out})$.

Comment: Oh I should've thought about the complement. How did you know that we should use conditional probability?

Comment: About the $x=r$ part, are we supposed to place every value of $r$ or only one value will suffice?

Comment: @kuhaku I feel "should" is a bit strong. It's a way that makes it simpler, it's not the only way. How I spotted it... describing how one spots the solution to a problem is always a bit difficult. I guess when you've got an event where there's not an obvious way to calculate it directly, finding some variable where the probability of our event conditional on that variable taking some value is easy to calculate is often the way to go. And using the previous part also seems likely, and it turns out that works.

Comment: @kuhaku If you've done part 1, you should know $p(x = r)$ for $r = 1, ..., 9$. Then if we call the event "the fish of type D gets taken out" $\mathcal D$, then the law of total probability says $p(\mathcal D) = \Sigma_{r = 1}^9 p(\mathcal D | x = r)p(x=r)$. So if you can work out $p(\mathcal D | x = r)$ then you can work out $p(\mathcal D)$.

Comment: Where did you get that from?

Comment: Oh nvm I didn't use the total probability.